# Level 2 Ask Price

Tags: stocks, penny-stocks, level-2-quotes

In the market depth image shown, watching in real-time, I noticed this behavior. The ask volume (260,000) wouldn't change even though transactions on the right kept hitting the ask price in volumes greater than the 260,000 displayed. Is is possible 260,000 number isn't a true representation? If so, how can one see the true volume for sale at the ask?

I'm not sure it makes a difference that this is a penny stock as I've noticed the same behavior on non-penny stocks.

[image: Market Depth]

Comment: What is the ticker? Is this Rennova Health, Inc. ([RNVA](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RNVA/overview))?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What trading platform is this? It could be an issue with your data source.

Comment: This particular view is from Schwab. (StreetSmart Edge)

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with your platform. This is what I see in thinkorswim (web version): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOcQ5.png

Comment: That's a much better view than what I'm getting. I'll have to inquire with Schwab. Thanks.

Comment: Do let us know about the results of your inquiry.

Comment: Schwab said they don't "create a market for OTC securities" so their view is not as detailed as brokerages that do.

Comment: They don't actually need to "create a market for OTC securities" to be able to show Level 2 quotes for OTC securities. All that they need to do is subscribe to the proper data feed from OTC Markets and Global OTC.

Comment: All Schwab needs to do is subscribe to these data feeds: [OTC Markets — Level 1 / Level 2 Data Products](https://www.otcmarkets.com/market-data/real-time-data-products/level-1-level-2-data-products) and [Global OTC — Proprietary Market Data](https://www.globalotc.com/market-data), but they did not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Pink Sheets but on major exchanges, hiiden orders offer traders the ability to disguise the size of their order, displaying only the order size that they want.

[Iceberg Order](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/icebergorder.asp):

> Iceberg orders are large orders that are split up into lots or small sized limit orders. They are split up into visible and hidden parts, with the latter transitioning to visibility after the former type of order is executed.

> They are typically placed by large institutional investors to avoid disrupting trading markets with a single, large order.

Comment: Got it, thank you.